# In my project ngOnInit called twice in angular with typescript only when refreshing the page and it happened with all pages

Tags: angular

In my project ngOnInit called twice in angular only when refreshing the page and it happened with all pages

I am expecting ngOninit called once when page refreshed.
I already checked no any component instialize twice or not any router-outlet repeat

Comment: Can you show your html and component code ? How are you implementing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @StefaniToto not possible to show actual components and HTML  because there are many components in my project

just for example 
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    
    selector: 'student-account-management',
    templateUrl: 'student-account-management.component.html'
})

export class studentAccountManagementComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {


    }
}

Comment: just for example 
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({  
    
    selector: 'student-account-management',  
    templateUrl: 'student-account-management.component.html'  
})  
  
export class studentAccountManagementComponent implements OnInit {  
  
    constructor() { }  
  
    ngOnInit() {  
  

    }  
}  `

Comment: Maybe you have implemented the tag to somewhere else also ? 
student-account-management

Comment: Can you check if your page is doing a redirect of any kind? This might be an actual page redirect due to SSO authentication with an existing auth cookie or an automatic navigation within your Angular app through Angular's routing module.

Comment: @StefaniToto I checked very clearly no anywhere tagged it

Comment: Can you debug than. Add a console log to your ngonitint.  Put a breakpoint/debugger on code to console.log and in broswer check the Stack Trace

Comment: @StefaniToto Automatic navigation within my Angular project through Angular's routing module

Comment: @StefaniToto I put a debugger in ngOninit and refreshed the page  debugger hit two times

Comment: ngOnInit being called twice after refreshing a page in an Angular application could indeed be related to routing. Routing-related problems can cause unexpected behavior in component initialization.

Comment: Great. Just check the  Stack Trace column and will show from were is getting called.